# Ignoring NUL value when reading textfile

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

I have this kind of tab delimited textfile

[image]

which i need to format to .CSV and Iam reading it like that

```
public static void ReadDelimitedFile(string docPath)
        {
            using (var writer = File.CreateText(@"outputFile.csv"))
            {
                using (var file = new StreamReader(docPath))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
                        {
                            var delimiters = new char[] { '\t' };
                            var segments = line.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                            foreach (var segment in segments)
                            {
                                writer.Write(segment+";");
                            }
                            writer.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried to use static method

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
```

but it does not ignore the NUL lines, how can i get rid of them ? What that symbol even mean ?

Thank you

Comment: One comment since the answers implied but did not state: `NUL` like that is a visual representation of the character with ascii value 0 (and indeed I think the value 0 in every encoding). So it is a 0 byte and is also called the NUL character. In general I consider seeing one of these to almost always be a bug somewhere, in part because many programs go horribly wrong if you give them a string with a NUL in it (for example C I believe uses NUL terminated strings so when reading this may well just consider it the end of the file at the first NUL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change it to something like:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.First() != 0x00)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
line = line.Trim('\0');
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    ....
```

Trim should remove any leading or trailing `nul`-characters from the string. To be totally sure to only remove the `nul` at the *end* of a line, use

```
line = line.TrimEnd('\0');
```

Comment: `NUL` isn't considered whitespace by `Trim`, you'll need to do `Trim('\0')` to get rid of them.

Comment: Why `Trim()` instead of `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`?

Comment: Because he didn't mention the .NET version. While `Trim` and `TrimEnd` are avaiable in all versions, `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is only present from 4.0 up.

Comment: @StevenLiekens: Have you tried seeing what `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("\0")` evaluates to? The simple answer to your question is that `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` isn't suitable for the job.

Comment: @Chris: Updated the call to `Trim` according to your comment.

Comment: @Chris so what about `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line.Trim('\0'))`

Comment: Nevermind, the updated answer doesn't trim whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare with `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[] {00})` or `Convert.ToChar(0)` instead. This should give you the null character ('\0') to compare with.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just use `'\0'` as you did in your last sentence than either of those first two?

Comment: It is... just to mention that there are always several ways to get it. ;-)